# Propagating checkboxes into grid list view

Tags: php, html, css

My site has a form and within it there is a locations section with 3 states, a select all locations checkbox, a County Title which on select checks all the towns/cities beneath it and the Towns/Cities  checkboxes. Here is the PHP to give you a better idea:

```
$str = '<input id="chkMaster" onclick="checkAllEnquiryLocation();" type="checkbox" value="AR000" name="location[]" /> <strong>All Locations</strong>'."\n"."<br>";
    $sql = "SELECT location_area_code, location_area_name FROM emg_location_area";
    $rs = $db->query($sql);
    if ($db->get_num_rows($rs))
    {
        while ($row = $db->fetch_row($rs))
        {
            $str .= '<div id="loco-column">';
            $area_Code = $row['location_area_code'];
            $area_Name = $row['location_area_name'];
            $str .= '<input onclick="checkAll_'.$area_Code.'()'.';" id="'.$area_Code.'" type="checkbox" value="'.$area_Code.'" name="location[]" /> <strong>'.$area_Name.'</strong>'."\n"."<br>";
            $xtpl->assign("function_id", $area_Code);

            $sql = "SELECT location_code, location_name 
                    FROM emg_location 
                    WHERE location_area_code='".$row['location_area_code']."'";
            $rs1 = $db->query($sql);
            if ($db->get_num_rows($rs1))
            {
                while ($row1 = $db->fetch_row($rs1))
                {
                    $k = $row1['location_code'];
                    $v = $row1['location_name'];
                    $str .= '<input id="'.$area_Code.'_'.$k.'" type="checkbox" value="'.$k.'" name="location[]" /> '.$v."\n"."<br/>";
                    $xtpl->assign("element_id", $area_Code."_".$k);
                    $xtpl->parse("main.area_check_all.element");
                }
                $xtpl->parse("main.area_check_all");
$str .= '</div>';
            }
        }
```

I want these to display like this: [Ebay's grid list view](http://www.ebay.co.uk/) if you scroll down the page you'll see how even though some listings are different sizes they fit inline and fill the selected area perfectly.

I thought this would be quite simple I have looked around and the only way i can see how to do this is with more php but is there a cleaner way to do this in CSS that anyone knows about?

Heres my attempt with css, it almost works but the smaller list of locations seem to get stuck on the right hand side of the container:

```
#loco-column{ display:inline-block; max-height:200px; float:left; padding-left:10px; margin-bottom:20px; }
```

Comment: Please show the resulting HTML, because the PHP isn't relevant here, AFAICS. Don't reference external websites, because either they are gone in the future or they will change over the years and then nobody will be able to reconstruct the question. Include everything necessary in your question.

Comment: OK Sorry the live example is here: [link](http://quotesin.co.uk) select Get a quote from the first slider and you'll see the Select Locations To Post Field :D Sorry for lack of this link

Comment: I added a sample HTML to your question. Even the link in your comment might be gone eventually.

Comment: I completely misunderstood your question, sorry for that. I reverted my changes to the previous version.